# Android Studios: How to use custom font?

Tags: java, fonts

I have a font ready in a folder named assets and I simply want to use this font on a button I have created. Any ideas on how I would go about this since I've watched tutorials and they don't seem to work on a button or at-least I may have made a mistake. I know about the code along these lines but I am not too sure where it would go in the main.

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Comment: Have you tried something along these lines? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder inside your assets folder named `fonts`, and add the .ttf file there. It is also possible your .ttf file is corrupted (happens quite often when downloading fonts).
If neither of these work, I need to see more code, because these are the only reasons it could fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to place your custom fonts in assets/fonts. In your Main Activity, you can create a public static Typeface to reference throughout your application, like:

```
public static Typeface myriadProRegular;
myriadProRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf");
```

Then in the Activity where you have your button, get the Button from the layout xml file and set it's typeface to your custom font:

```
btnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.event_calendar_add);
btnAdd.setTypeface(MainActivity.myriadProSemiBold);
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked though a stack of youtube videos and forums and this seemed to work.

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Retro.ttf");
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Not sure if it was the font since i have changed it from last time i tried but it has worked for me now.